# How to destroy user session from server

Tags: php, session

I have a blogging website in which users can post their ideas.
A user is posting some offensive things.
I have already deactivated that user from admin but the problem is that I am  still getting their posts.

After deeply analysing things and my current code I am pretty sure that the ban will take effect when user logs out from their current session.

So my question is how can I destroy session of that particular user without affecting other users.

I am using Php in backend.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: standard sessions = files. find their session id, get the session file location, then delete the corresponding file. usually it'd be `session_save_path() . 'sess_' . session_id()`

Comment: I don't have session I'd of that user..

Comment: take it up with the answer below then; nothing that already hasn't been said above.

Comment: When you say *"I am still getting their posts"* are you saying they are still able to post new posts because their session isn't destroyed and are still logged in?

Comment: Well anyway, if that is what you are saying and you have complete control over the site, presumably you know their `$_SESSION['username']` or have some determination of destination like `$_SESSION['usergroup']`? If so, after the `session_start()` just do something like `if($_SESSION['username'] == 'whatever') { session_destroy(); header("Location: where/ever"); exit; }` Something like that. Next time they post a message or navigate to a page, it *should* reload the page and destroy the session.

Comment: I have only userid of that user..how can I get $_SESSION ['username'] and usergroup of that user?

Comment: If the userid is stored as `$_SESSION['userid']`, then use that in place of `$_SESSION['username']`. You just need to identify the user uniquely is all. I don't know your system so I can't tell you what to use to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in session_destroy() function, or destory only one session..

Example:

```
unset($_SESSION['whatever']);
```

Comment: Go with my last comment.